# Datastructure for a collection of intervals

Tags: java, data-structures

I am looking for a Java based data structure which manages a collection time/date based intervals (preferably Joda Time) such that for every interval which is added to the collection, the data structure returns the subintervals(s) of the added interval, which are not yet in the data strucuture and consolidates the intervals.

Now in terms of set theory this would be easy, i.e. the return value would be "to be added" \ "existing" and the resulting structure would be "existing" union "to be added". Now of course I could emulate the date/time intervals using sets of discrete points but this seems not really effective.

So I am looking for an existing datastructure which already provides these set operations out of the box **using intervals**.

Just for clarification, here is an illustration of what I am looking for.

- existing: a collection of time intervals
- to be added: interval which should be added to the collection
- return value: the subintervals(s) of the interval which should be added which are not yet in the datastructure
- result: the collection of intervals including the one which has just been added

> ```
> //       case 0
> //       existing         *********************************************
> //       to be added                      ********
> //       return value                     --empty--  
> //       result           *********************************************
> //       
> //       case 1
> //       existing             *****************************************
> //       to be added      ************
> //       return value     ****
> //       result           *********************************************
> //       
> //       case 2
> //       existing               ***************************************
> //       to be added      ****
> //       return value     ****
> //       result           ****  ***************************************
> //       
> //       case 3
> //       existing         *****************************************
> //       to be added                                       ************
> //       return value                                              ****
> //       result           *********************************************
> //       
> //       case 4
> //       existing         ***************************************
> //       to be added                                               ****
> //       return value                                              ****
> //       result           ***************************************  ****
> //       
> //       case 5
> //       existing         *****************             ***************
> //       to be added                           ****
> //       return value                          ****
> //       result           *****************    ****     ***************
> //       
> //       case 6
> //       existing         *****************             ***************
> //       to be added                    ********
> //       return value                      *****
> //       result           **********************        ***************
> //       
> //       case 7
> //       existing         *****************             ***************
> //       to be added                               ********
> //       return value                              *****
> //       result           *****************        ********************
> //       
> //       case 8
> //       existing         *****************    ****     ***************
> //       to be added                     *****************
> //       return value                      ****    *****
> //       result           *********************************************
> //       
> //       ......
> //
> ```

Comment: Case 5 result is wrong am I right?

Comment: You have to write your own ADT. I can't think of any useful existing data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Guava Ranges](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained) may come in handy here. They already describe ranges/intervals, with some utility methods that help to create a data structure for maintaining these intervals as described in the question.

<sub>In fact, they are far more powerful than the intervals that are required here, assuming that *all* the intervals are [closed intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29#Including_or_excluding_endpoints) where the endpoints are included. But there's no reason to re-invent the wheel here, I guess.</sub>

The operations that are then required for the desired data structure are

- Computing the union of intervals. This is already offered by the `Range#span` method
- Detecting whether intervals overlap or at least are connected, or are enclosing each other. This is also offered by the `Range#isConnected` and `Range#encloses` methods.
- Computing the difference between intervals

The last one is *not* offered by the `Ranges` class - for a simple reason: The difference between two ranges may not be a single range, but *zero*, *one* or ***two*** ranges. But it can easily be built with a utility function, which returns a `List` of ranges, containing 0...2 elements, depending on the overlap configuration.

Here is a possible implementation of the desired data structure:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import com.google.common.collect.Range;

class Ranges
{
    // Computes the result of subtracting all the given ranges from
    // the given range.
    static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<Range<T>> subtractAll(
        Range<T> r, List<Range<T>> ranges)
    {
        List<Range<T>> currentList = Collections.singletonList(r);
        for (Range<T> other : ranges)
        {
            List<Range<T>> nextList = new ArrayList<Range<T>>();
            for (int i=0; i<currentList.size(); i++)
            {
                Range<T> current = currentList.get(i);
                List<Range<T>> differences = subtract(current, other);
                nextList.addAll(differences);
            }
            currentList = nextList;
        }
        return currentList;
    }

    // Computes the result of subtracting range r1 from
    // the given range r0. The result will be 
    // - an empty list if r1 encloses r0 
    // - an two-element list if r0 encloses r1
    // - a list containing r0 if the ranges are disjoint
    // - a single-element list otherwise 
    static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<Range<T>> subtract(
        Range<T> r0, Range<T> r1)
    {
        T min0 = r0.lowerEndpoint();
        T max0 = r0.upperEndpoint();
        T min1 = r1.lowerEndpoint();
        T max1 = r1.upperEndpoint();
        if (r0.encloses(r1))
        {
            List<Range<T>> result = 
                new ArrayList<Range<T>>();
            result.add(Range.closed(min0, min1));
            result.add(Range.closed(max1, max0));
            return result;
        }
        else if (r1.encloses(r0))
        {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        else if (r0.isConnected(r1))
        {
            T min = null;
            T max = null;
            if (min0.compareTo(min1) < 0)
            {
                min = min0;
                max = min1;
            }
            else
            {
                min = max1;
                max = max0;
            }
            return Collections.singletonList(Range.closed(min, max));
        }
        return Collections.singletonList(r0);
    }

    // "Normalize" the given list of ranges: As long as two of
    // them are connected, they are replaced by their "span" (union)
    static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<Range<T>> normalize(
        List<Range<T>> ranges)
    {
        List<Range<T>> currentList = new ArrayList<Range<T>>(ranges);
        while (true)
        {
            List<Range<T>> toRemove = new ArrayList<Range<T>>();
            List<Range<T>> toAdd = new ArrayList<Range<T>>();
            for (int i=0; i<currentList.size(); i++)
            {
                for (int j=i+1; j<currentList.size(); j++)
                {
                    Range<T> r0 = currentList.get(i);
                    Range<T> r1 = currentList.get(j);
                    if (r0.isConnected(r1))
                    {
                        toRemove.add(r0);
                        toRemove.add(r1);
                        toAdd.add(r0.span(r1));
                    }
                }
            }
            if (toAdd.isEmpty())
            {
                break;
            }
            Set<Range<T>> set = new LinkedHashSet<Range<T>>();
            set.addAll(currentList);
            set.removeAll(toRemove);
            set.addAll(toAdd);
            currentList = new ArrayList<Range<T>>(set);
        }
        return currentList;
    }

}


class RangesContainer<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
{
    private List<Range<T>> ranges;

    RangesContainer()
    {
        ranges = new ArrayList<Range<T>>();
    }


    public List<Range<T>> add(Range<T> newRange)
    {
        if (ranges.stream().anyMatch(r -> r.encloses(newRange)))
        {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        if (ranges.stream().noneMatch(r -> r.isConnected(newRange)))
        {
            ranges.add(newRange);
            ranges = Ranges.normalize(ranges);
            return Collections.singletonList(newRange);
        }
        List<Range<T>> differences = Ranges.subtractAll(newRange, ranges);
        ranges.add(newRange);
        ranges = Ranges.normalize(ranges);
        return differences;
    }


    List<Range<T>> getRanges()
    {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(ranges);
    }

}

public class RangesTest
{
    static final LocalDateTime ZERO = 
        LocalDateTime.of(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        testCase0();
        testCase1();
        testCase2();
        testCase3();
        testCase4();
        testCase5();
        testCase6();
        testCase7();
        testCase8();
    }


    private static void testCase0()
    {
        System.out.println("Test case 0");

        RangesContainer<LocalDateTime> rc = 
            new RangesContainer<LocalDateTime>();

        Range<LocalDateTime> existing0 = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(0),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(45));

        rc.add(existing0);

        Range<LocalDateTime> added = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(16),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(24));

        System.out.println("Existing:");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("Adding:");
        print("", added);

        List<Range<LocalDateTime>> returnValue = rc.add(added);

        System.out.println("Returned:");
        print(returnValue);

        System.out.println("Result");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    private static void testCase1()
    {
        System.out.println("Test case 1");

        RangesContainer<LocalDateTime> rc = 
            new RangesContainer<LocalDateTime>();

        Range<LocalDateTime> existing0 = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(4),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(45));

        rc.add(existing0);

        Range<LocalDateTime> added = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(0),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(12));

        System.out.println("Existing:");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("Adding:");
        print("", added);

        List<Range<LocalDateTime>> returnValue = rc.add(added);

        System.out.println("Returned:");
        print(returnValue);

        System.out.println("Result");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    private static void testCase2()
    {
        System.out.println("Test case 2");

        RangesContainer<LocalDateTime> rc = 
            new RangesContainer<LocalDateTime>();

        Range<LocalDateTime> existing0 = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(6),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(45));

        rc.add(existing0);

        Range<LocalDateTime> added = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(0),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(4));

        System.out.println("Existing:");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("Adding:");
        print("", added);

        List<Range<LocalDateTime>> returnValue = rc.add(added);

        System.out.println("Returned:");
        print(returnValue);

        System.out.println("Result");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    private static void testCase3()
    {
        System.out.println("Test case 3");

        RangesContainer<LocalDateTime> rc = 
            new RangesContainer<LocalDateTime>();

        Range<LocalDateTime> existing0 = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(0),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(41));

        rc.add(existing0);

        Range<LocalDateTime> added = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(33),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(45));

        System.out.println("Existing:");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("Adding:");
        print("", added);

        List<Range<LocalDateTime>> returnValue = rc.add(added);

        System.out.println("Returned:");
        print(returnValue);

        System.out.println("Result");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("\n");
    }


    private static void testCase4()
    {
        System.out.println("Test case 4");

        RangesContainer<LocalDateTime> rc = 
            new RangesContainer<LocalDateTime>();

        Range<LocalDateTime> existing0 = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(0),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(39));

        rc.add(existing0);

        Range<LocalDateTime> added = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(41),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(45));

        System.out.println("Existing:");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("Adding:");
        print("", added);

        List<Range<LocalDateTime>> returnValue = rc.add(added);

        System.out.println("Returned:");
        print(returnValue);

        System.out.println("Result");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    private static void testCase5()
    {
        System.out.println("Test case 5");

        RangesContainer<LocalDateTime> rc = 
            new RangesContainer<LocalDateTime>();

        Range<LocalDateTime> existing0 = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(0),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(17));
        Range<LocalDateTime> existing1 = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(30),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(45));

        rc.add(existing0);
        rc.add(existing1);

        Range<LocalDateTime> added = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(21),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(25));

        System.out.println("Existing:");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("Adding:");
        print("", added);

        List<Range<LocalDateTime>> returnValue = rc.add(added);

        System.out.println("Returned:");
        print(returnValue);

        System.out.println("Result");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("\n");
    }


    private static void testCase6()
    {
        System.out.println("Test case 6");

        RangesContainer<LocalDateTime> rc = 
            new RangesContainer<LocalDateTime>();

        Range<LocalDateTime> existing0 = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(0),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(17));
        Range<LocalDateTime> existing1 = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(30),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(45));

        rc.add(existing0);
        rc.add(existing1);

        Range<LocalDateTime> added = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(14),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(22));

        System.out.println("Existing:");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("Adding:");
        print("", added);

        List<Range<LocalDateTime>> returnValue = rc.add(added);

        System.out.println("Returned:");
        print(returnValue);

        System.out.println("Result");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("\n");
    }


    private static void testCase7()
    {
        System.out.println("Test case 7");

        RangesContainer<LocalDateTime> rc = 
            new RangesContainer<LocalDateTime>();

        Range<LocalDateTime> existing0 = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(0),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(17));
        Range<LocalDateTime> existing1 = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(30),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(45));

        rc.add(existing0);
        rc.add(existing1);

        Range<LocalDateTime> added = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(25),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(33));

        System.out.println("Existing:");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("Adding:");
        print("", added);

        List<Range<LocalDateTime>> returnValue = rc.add(added);

        System.out.println("Returned:");
        print(returnValue);

        System.out.println("Result");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    private static void testCase8()
    {
        System.out.println("Test case 8");

        RangesContainer<LocalDateTime> rc = 
            new RangesContainer<LocalDateTime>();

        Range<LocalDateTime> existing0 = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(0),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(17));
        Range<LocalDateTime> existing1 = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(21),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(25));
        Range<LocalDateTime> existing2 = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(30),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(45));

        rc.add(existing0);
        rc.add(existing1);
        rc.add(existing2);

        Range<LocalDateTime> added = Range.closed(
            ZERO.plusMinutes(15),
            ZERO.plusMinutes(31));

        System.out.println("Existing:");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("Adding:");
        print("", added);

        List<Range<LocalDateTime>> returnValue = rc.add(added);

        System.out.println("Returned:");
        print(returnValue);

        System.out.println("Result");
        print(rc.getRanges());

        System.out.println("\n");
    }


    static void print(List<Range<LocalDateTime>> list)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            Range<LocalDateTime> range = list.get(i);
            String message = String.format("%3d", i);
            print(message, range);
        }
    }

    static void print(String message, LocalDateTime t0, LocalDateTime t1)
    {
        long minutes0 = ZERO.until(t0, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        long minutes1 = ZERO.until(t1, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        System.out.printf("%10s:", message);
        for (long i=0; i<minutes0; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (long i=minutes0; i<minutes1; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    static void print(String message, Range<LocalDateTime> r)
    {
        print(message, r.lowerEndpoint(), r.upperEndpoint());
    }

}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Test case 0
Existing:
     0:*********************************************
Adding:
      :                ********
Returned:
Result
     0:*********************************************


Test case 1
Existing:
     0:    *****************************************
Adding:
      :************
Returned:
     0:****
Result
     0:*********************************************


Test case 2
Existing:
     0:      ***************************************
Adding:
      :****
Returned:
     0:****
Result
     0:      ***************************************
     1:****


Test case 3
Existing:
     0:*****************************************
Adding:
      :                                 ************
Returned:
     0:                                         ****
Result
     0:*********************************************


Test case 4
Existing:
     0:***************************************
Adding:
      :                                         ****
Returned:
     0:                                         ****
Result
     0:***************************************
     1:                                         ****


Test case 5
Existing:
     0:*****************
     1:                              ***************
Adding:
      :                     ****
Returned:
     0:                     ****
Result
     0:*****************
     1:                              ***************
     2:                     ****


Test case 6
Existing:
     0:*****************
     1:                              ***************
Adding:
      :              ********
Returned:
     0:                 *****
Result
     0:                              ***************
     1:**********************


Test case 7
Existing:
     0:*****************
     1:                              ***************
Adding:
      :                         ********
Returned:
     0:                         *****
Result
     0:*****************
     1:                         ********************


Test case 8
Existing:
     0:*****************
     1:                     ****
     2:                              ***************
Adding:
      :               ****************
Returned:
     0:                 ****
     1:                         *****
Result
     0:*********************************************
```

I took a `LocalDateTime` for the interval borders, but any `Comparable` object will do. The number of stars that is printed there is simply the number of minutes since an arbitrary `ZERO` `LocalDateTime`, for the tests.

### Notes:

Although the test cases that you described are covered here, and provide the desired results, additional tests could/should be introduced. For example, adding empty intervals, or adding intervals that lie exactly at the borders of two other intervals ... (that's why these are called **border** cases ;-))

I should also mention that the implementation is not necessarily the most efficient or elegant one. The `normalize` method that I introduced there could probably be avoided by diligent bookkeeping of the range borders, proabably using a `NavigableSet` or `NavigableMap` as suggested in another answer. Sophisticated data structures like [Interval Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) may also be worth a look if performance is crucial. But I think that the given implementation is reasonable and comparatively easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

There is no ready structure for this, at least not in stdlib or commons, but you can relatively easily implement something using a `NavigableMap` (`TreeMap`).  Especially methods like `floorEntry()`/`ceilingEntry()` and `subMap()` should be useful for this.

In our application we have a range aggregator class that computes sum of allocations for ranges. I.e. base input is a set of (maybe overlapping) date ranges with numbers attached to them. The output is the set of corresponding non-overlapped ranges, with numbers from input summed where input ranges overlap. It is less than 100 lines of code and uses a `TreeMap`.

Comment: Do you use the interval start or enddate as keys for the TreeMap or are you using some kind of combined key? Furthermore, are you using immutable interval representations or are you modifying them?

Comment: We use just the dates. In our case the map is `{ date -> sum_till_the_next_date }` (the last entry maps to zero). When adding another range we recompute its content. This involves possibly inserting new entries, if we don't have such date(s) in the map yet, as well as adding the assigned value to all ranges in the `subMap()` for start/end dates.